# can't concat str to bytes when trying to unzip remote contents in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting raw ziped content from a remote API, this content is stored in `response.text` variable. If I print it right away, I do see some abracadabra symbols, so this content is zipped. I want to unzip and check its value via logger. I tried to do it like so:

```
buffer = StringIO(response.text)
content = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buffer)
logging.info(content)
#logging.info(content.read())
#logging.info(content.read().decode("utf-8"))
```

But in all cases, I get this error message:

> can't concat str to bytes

What is wrong with this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Generally you must convert between string and bytes with "encode" or "decode" method when needed. You can't just mix the types.

Comment: Is the from the `requests` module? Which line has the error?

Comment: The error is raised at the line `logging.info(....`

Comment: @Michael Butscher. So, what is the right way to do this - read raw zip contents, unzip it and put it to the log?

Comment: @tdelaney. Yes, `requests` module is used here

Comment: Is there anything in `response.headers`, especially Content-Type and Content-Encoding? The right stuff may be in `response.content`. https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content

Comment: @tdelaney. You are right. I solved it using `zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(response.content))`

Comment: In `response.headers` is Content-Encoding gzip? It seems like either the API botched the header or double-zipped the content.

Comment: @tdelaney. I found out that the format is `zip`, not `gz`. But overall yu were right, that `response.content` should be used instead of `response.text`.